# hacer Bind de datos para ejecutar insert de multiples Registros

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, refactoring

Tengo un método que hace `Insert` y `Updates` en PHP a una Base de Datos `MySQL` usando PDO.

En este caso la estructura de las tablas no es relevante ya que si el query no cumple con los datos de cada columna mínimamente necesario el Script hará un roleback del insert.

Este Script tiene un grave error y es que ejecuta los insert y update desde un query string ***armado como texto plano***.

***Que recibe el Método?***

***Nota:*** estos query son un ejemplo, no siempre son iguales o similares pueden variar dependiendo del escenario, los datos tambien pueden cambiar; pero la teoría es que siempre se recibe un query string de insert o Update.

Actualmente un `array` con la siguiente estructura de ejemplo:

```php
    $dbquery =[
        'DB1'=>[
            '0' =>'INSERT INTO table_name(column1,column2,column3) VALUES (value11,value21,value31)',
            '1' =>'INSERT INTO table_name(column1,column2,column3) VALUES (value21,value22,value23)',
            '2' =>'INSERT INTO table_name(column1,column2,column3) VALUES (value31,value32,value33)',
        ],
        'DB2'=>[
            '0' =>'INSERT INTO table_name(column1,column2,column3) VALUES (value41,value42,value43)',
            '1' =>'INSERT INTO table_name(column1,column2,column3) VALUES (value51,value52,value53)',
            '2' =>'INSERT INTO table_name(column1,column2,column3) VALUES (value61,value62,value63)',
        ],
    ];
```

***El Script Usado es este:***

El cual toma la estructura de ejmplo y la recorre... haciendo intercambio de base de datos, tablas y ejecutando cada Query (Insert, Update) para al final realizar un commit:

```php
public function SetData($Query, $Conf = [])
    {
        try {
            $conn = $this->DataBaseConnection($this->CheckServerSwitch($Conf)); //establece la conexion
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $conn->beginTransaction();
            $conn->exec("set names utf8");
            foreach ($Query as $DB_2USE => $QArr) {
                $conn->exec('USE ' . $DB_2USE);
                foreach ($QArr as $key => $QString) {
                    $cQ = $conn->exec($QString); //ejecuta el query
                    if ($this->CheckIfStartWith(['str' => $QString, 'beg' => 'UPDATE'])) { //valida si es un Update
                        $count['u'] = $count['u'] + $cQ;
                    }
                    if ($this->CheckIfStartWith(['str' => $QString, 'beg' => 'INSERT'])) { //valida si es un Insert
                        $count['i'] = $count['i'] + $cQ;
                    }
                    ++$cT;
                }
            }
            if (0 != $count['i']) {
                $smgINS_TXT = 'Registros Insertados: ' . $count['i'] . '<br>';
            }
            if (0 != $count['u']) {
                $smgUPD_TXT = 'Registros Actualizados: ' . $count['u'];
            }
            $conn->commit();
            return $smgINS_TXT . $smgUPD_TXT;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            $conn->rollback();
            return ['error'=>true, 'type'=>6, 'obj'=>$e]
        }
    }
```

***Preguntas/Dudas:***

En la investigación realizada los ejemplos que encuentro Ejemplos que implemntan de bind (bindValue, bindParam) usan un solo insert, pero en mi escenario estoy tratando de insertar/actualizar varios registro, para que al finalizar pueda hacer el commit y si existiera algún error hago rollback y evito datos mal insertados... pero no estoy implementando **bind**...

***¿Cómo es la implementación de `Bind` cuando el escenario es el que presento?***

Se que debo partir cambiado mi array a algo como estos:

```php
    $dbquery =[
        'DB1'=>[
            '0' =>[
                'query' => 'INSERT INTO table_name(column1,column2,column3) VALUES (?,?,?)',
                'column1'=>value11,
                'column2'=>value12,
                'column3'=>value13,
            ],
            '1' =>[
                'query' => 'INSERT INTO table_name(column1,column2,column3) VALUES (?,?,?)',
                'column1'=>value21,
                'column2'=>value22,
                'column3'=>value23,
            ],
            '2' =>[
                'query' => 'INSERT INTO table_name(column1,column2,column3) VALUES (?,?,?)',
                'column1'=>value31,
                'column2'=>value32,
                'column3'=>value33,
            ],
        ],
        'DB2'=>[
            '0' =>[
                'query' => 'INSERT INTO table_name(column1,column2,column3) VALUES (?,?,?)',
                'column1'=>value41,
                'column2'=>value42,
                'column3'=>value43,
            ],
            '1' =>[
                'query' => 'INSERT INTO table_name(column1,column2,column3) VALUES (?,?,?)',
                'column1'=>value51,
                'column2'=>value52,
                'column3'=>value53,
            ],
            '2' =>[
                'query' => 'INSERT INTO table_name(column1,column2,column3) VALUES (?,?,?)',
                'column1'=>value61,
                'column2'=>value62,
                'column3'=>value63,
            ],
        ],
    ];
```

Otro ejemplo del Array pero con nodos diferentes:

```php
$dbquery =[
        'DB1'=>[
            '0' =>[
                'query' => 'INSERT INTO table_name_1(column1,column2) VALUES (?,?)',
                'column1'=>value11,
                'column2'=>value12,
            ],
            '1' =>[
                'query' => 'INSERT INTO table_name_2(column1,column2,column3,column4) VALUES (?,?,?,?)',
                'column1'=>value21,
                'column2'=>value22,
                'column3'=>value23,
                'column4'=>value24,
            ],
        ],
    ];
```

***pero que cambios debo hacer a mi script (caso de refactorizar)?***

Comment: ¿La tabla y las columnas son siempre las mismas, o cada cuánto pueden cambiar?

Comment: Esos artilugios entre la lógica de negocio y el SQL suelen tener un costo, y lo que debemos preguntarnos es ¿qué valor aportan?.
Todo esfuerzo requerido en modificar el arreglo para implementar sentencias preparadas mejor ocúpalo en implementar sentencias preparadas desde un inicio, es decir, que en lugar de tener un ciclo generando un arreglo de SQLs, en ese mismo ciclo controla la ejecución -y el commit- de las sentencias preparadas.

Comment: No precismente Sr Poderoso, puse esa respuesta por que el formato de código no lo apreciarías en el comentario. La aportación está ahí y hay mucho detrás de ella, es cuestión que la tomes, sugiero que con calma. La idea es darte ideas para que continúes investigando. Con tu idea estas desaprovechando la esencia de la sentencia preparada.